# How can I find out if someone is using their device to look at things on my device

Tags: privacy

I would like to know about this information  because  I think my girlfriend is spying on my phone

Comment: Can you be more explicit?

Comment: Can you please add your concerns (Ex: "I see that my sms's is open when i didint open it")?

Comment: What makes you think so?

Answer (score 3):

If you suspect someone of snooping on your electronic devices, you have to assume that person is tech-savvy enough to avoid being detected; especially with methods learnt on a public community site.

Plant a false information compelling that person to perform a certain action (like spying physically) or reveal knowledge of that information, and verify the result -- sort of a [canary trap](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Canary_trap) intended to confirm the leak rather than identify the culprit.

Comment: It's a phone, probably an android or iPhone. I'm sure there are spy-apps that can be hidden from the menu and installed by complete beginners. So all the other person would have to do is gain unattended access to the phone for a couple of minutes. If that's the case, everything is possible.